# При установке OnlyOffice выбивает ошибку - ERROR 1045

Tags: debian, onlyoffice

Когда пробую установить на Debian 8 OnlyOffice - выдает такую ошибку

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

пароль верный, так как под рутом подключаюсь к базе. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/16.html

Comment: спасибо, но эту статью я читал и она не решает моей проблемы. у меня есть пользователь ***root*** и пароль у него верный

Comment: такого пользователя в mysql не может быть. может быть `пользователь@машина`. перечитайте статью ещё раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: пользователь ***root*** есть и может быть, вы путаете комбинацию имени пользователя и хоста. да, у меня есть комбинация 'root'@'localhost' и я знаю пароль, но это не работает